# getLine doesn't stop

Tags: haskell, user-input, ghc

My program goes something like

```
main :: IO String
main = do
  putStrLn "input a"
  a <- getChar
  putStrLn "input b"
  b <- getLine
  putStrLn "input c"
  c <- getChar
  return a:c:b
```

Behaviour: I get "input a" printed, and the program waits for me to type a Char and press return. From there, it scrolls past **getLine** without ever letting me input something. How can I make it do what I intend it to?

P.S.: There are probably more problems with this code, but let's focus on my present question.

Comment: Is this your actual code? Have you tried to run it? Your snippet doesn't compile for me because you are missing parentheses around `a:c:b`. When I add the parentheses it behaves as expected.

Comment: I think you should probably disable buffering (with [hSetBuffering](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hSetBuffering)) - this should fix those issues

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you press <kbd>X</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> you get `X\n` into your keyboard buffer.

`getChar` reads `X` but leaves `\n`. Then `getLine` just reads `\n` and finishes immediately.

You can read trailing `\n` with another `getLine` to clean keyboard buffer before reading `b`

```
main :: IO String
main = do
  putStrLn "input a"
  a <- getChar
  getLine --clean kbd buffer
  putStrLn "input b"
  b <- getLine
  putStrLn "input c"
  c <- getChar
  return (a:c:b)
```

Comment: While using `stdin NoBuffering` was the correct thing to do, this answer explained the problem better. The actual code has multiple `do` statements. In order to understand in which ones to use `stdin NoBuffering` I needed to understand what was happening in the first place. There is no reason why I should change `stdout` defaults.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is caused by   **stdin buffering** that is enabled by default.

1. **Import IO at top level of your file**

   ```
   import System.IO
   ```
2. Add to your **main** (before any *getChar* call)

   ```
   hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
   ```

```haskell
import System.IO
main = do
  hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
  putStrLn "input a"
  a <- getChar
  putStrLn "input b"
  b <- getLine
  putStrLn "input c"
  c <- getChar
  print $ a:(c:b)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think I know what you are talking about (even if your code does not compile) and this should fix it (at least it does usual.y for me):

```
import System.IO

hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
```

BTW: I think I have those issues in *eshell* and on windows inside GHCi but I am not 100% sure - never had in bash though

---

of course it might be the strange combination of `getChar` and `getLine` too ;)

Anyway this:

```
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do

  hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
  hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering

  putStrLn "input a"
  a <- getLine
  putStrLn "input b"
  b <- getLine
  putStrLn "input c"
  c <- getLine
  print (a,b,c)
```

should print the prompt and let you enter the 3 inputs, finally printing the tuple